# Access Object Variables with PHP

Tags: php, object

What is the correct method to access the variables in an object in PHP? These don't seem to work.

```
$response = $wepay->request('checkout/create', array(
    'account_id'        => $account_id,
    'amount'            => '24.95',
    'short_description' => 'A brand new soccer ball',
    'type'              => 'GOODS',
    'mode'              => 'regular'


));

// display the response
print_r($response);
//prints stdClass Object ( [checkout_id] => 466761864 [checkout_uri] => https://stage.wepay.com/api/checkout/466761864/6c60270d )

echo $response[checkout_id]; //nothing
echo $response->$checkout_id; //nothing
var_dump(get_object_vars($response));  //nothing
```

I just need to get the [checkout_id] and the [checkout_uri] from $response. 
I'm new to php objects, but from looking around, these were all ways people said to do it, they just aren't working in this case. Sorry if this is way simple.

Comment: Trivial matter of PHP syntax, solved by looking at literally *any* object-oriented PHP code. You should always do at least *some* research before posting questions to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When accessing object properties using the `->` operator, the property names MUST NOT prepended by a `$`.

This will work for you:

```
echo $response->checkout_id;
```

You can follow the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php)